# Attempted import error: 'yup' does not contain a default export (imported as 'yup'). NPM

Tags: node.js, react, npm, yup

Estou criando um site com serviço de autenticação e nele pretendo usar o yup, um modulo do NPM.
Instalei tudo certo mas quando vou dar start na aplicação ele aparece:

```
Attempted import error: 'yup' does not contain a default export (imported as 'yup').
```

Já tentei diversas coisas mas sempre o mesmo erro no npm.

Comment: insira no final do código o "export default yup"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está importando o yup no seu projeto ? Ele não possui um export padrão, sendo assim, não dá para importar desta forma: `import yup from 'yup'`, você precisa importá-lo assim `import * as yup from 'yup'` para ter acesso a todos os recursos, ou desestruturar para um recurso específico. [Veja aqui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#usage).